# More about SWFScan

Tags: apache-flex, security, flash, decompiling

I'm desperate to find the ShmooCon talk by HP's Prajakta Jagdale on SWFScan and flash decompilation. All I could find was the HP white paper itself. Anyone who can help, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Shoot Prajakta an email. prajakta.jagdale {RMV}@{ME} hp.com.